# Why are backspace handled two times?

Tags: ios, flutter

I have simple demo app with a TextField and a TextEditingController. When I triyng

When I open the app in the iOS simulator then I getting two events when I put backspace. I expected only one event.

Step to reproduce:

1. Put text - for example `x`
2. Click on the backspace.

In console output I see:

```
flutter: current value: x
flutter: current value: x
flutter: current value:
```

But I expected

```
flutter: current value: x
flutter: current value:
```

Why I see `x` two times?

Here is my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Backspace demo'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: BackspaceDemo(),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

class BackspaceDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BackspaceDemoState createState() {
    return _BackspaceDemoState();
  }
}

class _BackspaceDemoState extends State<BackspaceDemo> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(handleTextChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void handleTextChange() {
    print("current value: " + _controller.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
        controller: _controller,
        autocorrect: false,
        autofocus: true,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "Enter a text ...",
        ));
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try creating your TextField in the initState and then return the var (which calls your textfield) in the build function?

Comment: Hi @jirkapenzes , have you solved the problem? I just encountered the same problem. I wonder how did you handle this? Thanks a lot.